# Objects passed to methods

Tags: java

Can anyone please help a newcomer to the world of Java with the below code:

```
//Objects may be passed to methods

package Training;

public class Test {
    int a, b;

    Test(int i, int j) {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }

    //Return true if o is equal to the invoking object
    boolean equalTo(Test o) {
        if(o.a == a && o.b == b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

class PassOb {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test ob1 = new Test(100, 22);
        Test ob2 = new Test(100, 22);
        Test ob3 = new Test(-1, -1);

        System.out.println("ob1 == ob2: " + ob1.equalTo(ob2));
        System.out.println("ob1 == ob3: " + ob1.equalTo(ob3));
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain what is happening in this code, especially the

```
boolean equalTo(Test o) {
        if(o.a == a && o.b == b) return true;
        else return false;
```

block of code.

Comment: Looks like this method is testing AND as if you were looking at a truth table...Returns true if a AND b are 1, else it would return false

Comment: It tests of your `Test` class instance is equal to some other passed in `Test` class instance with name `o`. It does this by comparing both classes instance variables with name `a` and `b`. If both are identical it returns true.

Comment: shorter form : return (o.a == a && o.b == b);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 boolean equalTo(Test o) {
    if(o.a == a && o.b == b) return true;
    else return false;
```

compares the `this` object with `o` for equality - here defined as "Test x equalsTo() Test y if and only if they have the same a and b values."  == operator is OK for comparing int, because it is a primitive, immutable type.

`o.a == a` : the a value is the same

`&&` : AND

`o.b == b` : the b value is the same.

It's `((o.a == a) && (o.b == b))` and not `((o.a == (a && o.b)) == b)` because of operator precedence rules: `==` binds before `&&`.  That's fortunate, since the latter parenthesization is nonsense - you can't logical-and two integers in Java.

(Normally in Java we'd implement `Object.equals()`, not `equalsTo()`, for this functionality.)

Comment: I get what is happening in the first block, and the last, i know this is going to be a really horrible dumb question but i don't understand what boolean equalTo(Test o) is referring to, or the if(o.a == a && o.b == b) return true;

Comment: Where is it getting the o.a and o.b from?
Also i don't really get why i take the middle block out then the rest of the code wont compile since i thought the .equalTo bit in the last block of code would suffice?

Comment: `o` is an object of type Test passed into equalsTo() - when it runs, some caller will have provided the exact `o` that will be examined.  The `o.a` and `o.b` expressions refer to the members a and b of object `o`. The boolean equalsTo() is referring to is the return value of equalsTo() - the value that is produced by evaluated the expression to the right of the 'return' keyword.

Comment: You're /defining/ the equalsTo() method of the class Test - it in no way is pre-existing.  In the last block, you call it, but that middle block defines it.  You can't call it without defining it.